# Java Static Method to Parse Generic Enum Set from String

Tags: java, generics, enums, set

I have a lot of classes which define some Enum whose values I want loaded from a user-entered String. So I find myself repeating the method:

```
public final class Status {
    public static enum TYPE { Slow, Haste, Sleep, Stop, Stone, Invis, Rage,
        Conf, Bleed, Weak, Dumb, Sil, Rot, Lev, Clumsy };

    public static Set<Status.TYPE> typesFromString(String string) { 
        EnumSet<Status.TYPE> set = EnumSet.noneOf(Status.TYPE.class);
        if (string == null)
            return set;
        String[] elements = string.split(",");
        for (String element : elements) {
            element = element.trim();
            for (TYPE type : EnumSet.allOf(Status.TYPE.class)) {
                if (type.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(element)) {
                    set.add(type);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return set;
    }
```

Which is to say, given a string which contains comma-separated elements which match the enum entries, return a set populated with each match.

I'd love to make this generic, so I wouldn't have to maintain ten different copies of it, but I can't quite figure out how to make this generic while returning a set of enums. I think it would look vaguely like the following method:

```
public static Set<[Enum Class Specified in Argument]> setFromString(String string, [Class of Enum to Work With]) {
    Set<E extends Enum<E>> set = EnumSet.noneOf([Class of Enum]);
    if (string == null)
        return set;
    for (String element : string.split(",")) {
        element = element.trim().toLowerCase();
        for ([Element of Enum] type : EnumSet.allOf([Class of Enum])) {
            if (type.toString().trim().toLowerCase().equals(element))
                set.add(type);
        }
    }
}
return set;
```

Comment: Unrelated comment: the code convention to enum types is to use uppercase (i.e. `SLOW, HASTE, SLEEP, STOP...` instead of `Slow, Haste, Sleep, Stop...`)

Comment: Agreed, but I'd also like to display from these values directly, and I don't want the user seeing all-caps. If there's any way to have the best of both worlds, I'm all ears.

Comment: Then here: use uppercase for the enum constants, and then use `set.add(Enum.valueOf(myEnumClazz, element.toUpperCase()))`, which also avoids the loop.  There's prebuilt utilities for getting an enum constant by name.

Comment: You misunderstand -- I want to later be able to call `toString()` on a `Status.TYPE` and display the results as I currently have them typed. If I convert the enum entries to upper-case, I'll get upper-case output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify the generic parameter (`<E extends Enum<E>`) between the modifiers (`public static`) and the return value (`Set<E>`). And pass as an argument the `Class` of the enum (`Class<E>` clazz`). Which should look something like this:

```
    public static <E extends Enum<E>> Set<E> parseValues(
        String string, Class<E> clazz
    ) { 
        EnumSet<E> set = EnumSet.noneOf(clazz);
        if (string == null) {
            return set; // ( better, NPE )
        }
        String[] elements = string.split(",");
        for (String element : elements) {
            element = element.trim();
            for (E type : EnumSet.allOf(clazz)) {
                if (type.name().equalsIgnoreCase(element)) {
                    set.add(type);
                    break;
                }
            }
            // ( Do we really want to ignore spurious values? )
        }
        return set;
    }
```

(Not tested or compiled.)

Comment: Yep, that did the trick. I guess I need to brush up on my generics, since I get the gist of what's going on when I read it but I was trying to define it with the signature `public static Set<E extends Enum<E>>` which was freaking Java out. Thanks. (Also, the comment about spurious values is great for posterity. I'm still thinking about it in my use case.)